# Why did I have to place a 100 reputation bounty instead of 50?

Tags: support, bounty

I have recently wanted to post a bounty for 50 points however 50 points was not an option that appeared when I clicked "start a bounty". This forced me to post the [bounty of 100 points](https://superuser.com/questions/520357/program-broke-my-windows-everything-randomly-minimizes-even-after-multiple-rest).

I have read the FAQ about the bounties and there didn't seem to be anything about this behavior in it. I wonder if there are any additional rules to posting a bounty that might force you to post a higher bounty.  I noticed that there are already a lot (30) of bounty questions asked on this site and possibly it's a mechanism from keeping the bounty number lower?

Could someone explain to me exactly why I couldn't post a lower bounty of 50 on my question? Maybe I'm just silly and missed something in FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> Note: If you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

You posted an answer, so you need to offer 100. Here, the fact that this answer was deleted again obviously isn't taken into account.

Comment: ah i see so it is my mistake. Sorry